# how to design table in sql server for obtaining summary results

Tags: sql-server

I got this situation. Logic is customer will be given credit sale and they will repay money in installments. I need to store this details about products, qty and the amounts they are giving in installments.

In dashboard i need to show all customers with name total sale amount, paid amount and balance amount.

**Approach i thought**

> tblCredit = Stores as rows for all the time they pay amount
>
> (e.g)  shan(Name),  paper (product), 1500 (qty) , 2000 (Price), 100
>   (Debit) {           initial purchase) }
>           shan (Name), -, -, -, 200 (Debit)
>
> In query filter by name and sum(Price) - Sum(Debit amount) will give
>   balance

But this approach once the data grows is this aggregation will be trouble some ?

> Is it possible like caching the aggregated result with timestamps or
>   something like that and update that at every operation when we are
>   inserting data in that table and show result from that ?

**Note**

> Data growth rate will be high.

I am very new to designing.

Please guide me the best approach to handle this.

**Update**

Apart from dashboard i need to show report when users clicks report to know how much credit given for whom. So in any case i need a optimized query and logic and design to handle this.

Comment: This feels like a question that would get much better treatment over at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Usually a dashboard do not need to get the data in real time. You may think of using data snapshot (schedule data insert after your aggregation) rather than maintaining a summary table update by different types of sales transactions, which is difficult in maintaining the integrity especially handling back-day process.